# Image exactly in middle in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am getting problem where i am trying to display image exactly in the middle of the screen of 
UIView *userView.

```
 userView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, KVWDT, KVHGT)];//KVWDT=300 & KVHGT=400.
```

and my image view is to display only on the upper half of the user view, at bottom i am displaying some other fields also

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:[dic objectForKey:@"img"]];  
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
CGRect imgFrame = imageView.frame;
```

How should i display the image exactly in the middle of userView. Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter
imageView.center = userView.center;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use something like

```
imageView.center = userView.center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the UIImageView frame the same frame as the view.  Then set UIImageView contentMode property to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, KVWDT, KVHGT)] autorelease];
imageView.image = image;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[userView addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i came up with the solution

```
    CGSize boundsSize = userView.frame.size;
    CGRect imgFrameToCenter = imageView.frame;
    //center horizontally
    if (imgFrameToCenter.size.width<boundsSize.width) {
        imgFrameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width-imgFrameToCenter.size.width)/2;

    }
    else{
        imgFrameToCenter.origin.x=0;
    }
```